# Return false in JS Coffee Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I am working in `coffee script` where i want to return false if value blank of field so i write a code below in jQuery which work perfect but in `coffee script not working return false.`

I tried lot but not getting any proper solutions ..

```
#jQuery Code
$("#retFalse a").click(function(e) {
    if($("#testdiv").val() == "") {
     alert("Value required");
     return false;
    }
});

#JS Coffee script code
$('#retFalse a').click (e) ->
  if $('#testdiv').val() == ''
    alert 'Value required'
    return false
  return
```

Any one have a solution. Thanks

Comment: #testdiv value if user fill whatever but if blank then need to alert messag and return false and not go for further process..